# spark job server api dependency not found. what can i do?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Im putting the following in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>spark.jobserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>job-server-api_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to use other versions too but maven don't seem to find any of them.

what can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark Jobserver uses Jitpack. See https://jitpack.io/#spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver_2.11

Answer (score 0):

PLease add the following repository in your pom file

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>Artifactory</id>
<name>Artifactory</name>
<url>https://sparkjobserver.jfrog.io/artifactory/jobserver/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

As of now only 0.8.1, 0.11.1 and 1.10.2 versions are available. so please change the dependency to

```
<dependency>
<groupId>spark.jobserver</groupId>
<artifactId>job-server-api_2.11</artifactId>
<version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```